# React - Conditional rendering is not working well

Tags: reactjs

The component I have added here gets rendered post login. All I needed is to redirect to login when the session has expired. My problem is mainly inside render. On successful login, the page gets redirected to Home and shows `this.state.success.toString()` as true and as false if the session has expired. Till this, is fine. 
When I uncomment the lines I left commented, and comment out the last line, render function is to either show a message in Home or redirect to login.
But code doesn't work that way. It goes to the Home route and again gets redirected to Login. Even the `componentDidUpdate()` method didn't get called. I couldn't understand why. Could you please help to solve this?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      success: "",
      message: "",
      user: "",
      cookies: ""
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/auth/login/success', { withCredentials: true }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      let data = res.data;
      if (this._isMounted) {
        this.setState({
          success: data.success,
          message: data.message,
          user: data.user ? data.user : "",
          cookies: data.cookies ? data.cookies : ""
        })
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      let data = err.response.data;
      if (this._isMounted)
        this.setState({
          success: data.success,
          message: data.message,
          user: data.user ? data.user : "",
          cookies: data.cookies ? data.cookies : ""
        });
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
  render() {
    // if (this.state.success)
    //   return <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
    // else {
    //   return <Redirect to="/login"></Redirect>
    // }
    return <h1>{this.state.success.toString()}</h1>

  }
  componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
    console.log(this.state);

  }
}
```

Comment: Try storing the redirect logic in `componentDidMount` rather than `render`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you make an API call and the data retrieval is asynchronous, you must maintain a loading indicator to process your logic once the data is received, otherwise during the initial render the `success` state will be false and your component will be Redirected due to `Redirect` component being render

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      success: "",
      message: "",
      user: "",
      cookies: ""
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/auth/login/success', { withCredentials: true }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      let data = res.data;
      if (this._isMounted) {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          success: data.success,
          message: data.message,
          user: data.user ? data.user : "",
          cookies: data.cookies ? data.cookies : ""
        })
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      let data = err.response.data;
      if (this._isMounted)
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          success: data.success,
          message: data.message,
          user: data.user ? data.user : "",
          cookies: data.cookies ? data.cookies : ""
        });
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
  render() {
    if(isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>

     if (this.state.success)
       return <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
     else {
       return <Redirect to="/login"></Redirect>
     }

  }
  componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
    console.log(this.state);

  }
}
```